# Align placeholder further right

Tags: html, css

I have an input field and want the placeholder `E-Mail` to be further right for example `25px` so that there is place to add an svg.

```css
.input-field {
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input class="input-field" placeholder="Email">
```

I could add `text-align: center;` to the css class but that doesn't solve my problem because thats too far on the right side.

```css
.input-field {
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input class="input-field" placeholder="Email">
```

**Update: I tried to implement the code suggested by @Tom.**

It works **BUT** only on input {}. I want it to apply only to .input-field input {} but that doesn't work.

```css
.input-field {
    width: 300px;
}

.input-field input {
    width: 300px;
    text-indent: 25px;
}

input {
    text-indent: 25px;
}
```

```html
<input class="input-field" placeholder="Email">
```

Comment: There are 14 answers on the linked duplicate and you tried ALL of them? Simple `padding-left: 25px` would seem to solve it.

Comment: The selector should be `input.input-field` not `.input-field input`

Comment: Tom thanks works now! @Paulie_D simple padding-left don't work because than the input field increases further on the right side.

Comment: PS Your selector `.input-field input ` is incorrect since `.input-field` IS the input. You want `input.input-field`

Comment: Padding left WILL work provide you are using `box-sizing; border-box`

Comment: @Paulie_D my fault, works now too! Thanks!